# Unsupported operand type on method

Tags: python, types, int, operands

I have a method on a Python class which aims to get an average number:

```
def get_average_rating(self):
    rated_books = 0
    book_sum = 0
    for book in self.books:
        rated_books += 1
        book_sum += self.books[book]
    return book_sum/rated_books
```

But I get the error message:

> ```
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
> ```

I've tried to nail this for days already and although the value pass through, I receive this alert and would like to deliver it clean. I saw many related questions, [like this][1], but still couldn't understand. Can someone throw some light here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It means `self.books[book] == None`, not an integer which you might have expected. What are the contents of `self.books`?

Comment: book_sum += self.books[book] is the problem. What are the contents of "book"? What (which variable in "book") do you wanna sum to book_sum?

Comment: meowgoesthedog,  self.books[book] is supposed to retrieve a value for a key on a dictionary that comes tied to a specific class ("self" referring to users on the system whose book list (self.books) carry book names and their ratings by their user).

Comment: akhavro, in the dictionary of books for each user (self.books), book refers to a key-value pair. Each item of self.books iterates untill all books have their ratings compared. rated_books is the amount of books within the dictionary (so per each book processed, it adds 1), and book_sum is the sum of all ratings which will be divided by the amount of books and get the average rating.

Comment: where you read "book list", please see "book dictionary" (just to avoid confusion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error when you try to add `None` to an `int` value. In your case, it's happening on the line

```
book_sum += self.books[book]
```

We know that `book` is in `self.books` (because we're inside the `for` loop), but `self.books[book]` must be `None`.

Comment: Thanks to you all. The issue has been solved. I could find the None statement and solve it. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the insight. It helped me to find a solution. The way it was, the value was really None.